# How to setup Mockoon for Android emulator?

Tags: android, mocking, mockoon

I'm trying to use [mockoon](https://mockoon.com/) for running a mock API to test an Android app (using Retrofit2) on my macOS.

Using `0.0.0.0:[port]` or `localhost:[port]` as the address doesn't work.

Any idea what I should be doing differently?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `10.0.2.2:[port]` for the default emulator and `10.0.3.2:[port]` for Genymotion

Edit `AndroidManifest.xml` to allow `usesCleartextTraffic` and internet permissions.

```
<manifest 
....
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    ....
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ....
</application>
```

P.S. Remember to disable `usesCleartextTraffic` before deploying app to production!

Comment: Don't risk it by editing the main manifest. Just add it to debug/integration manifest instead.